# Quick and easy way to plot a copied list of numbers as a line chart in MS Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, copy-paste, diagrams

I have a copy pasted list of numbers.

I want to plot it in Excel as a line chart.

How can I do this, without having to add labels etc. to the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the quickest and easiest way to plot a list of numbers from your clipboard as a line chart:

1. Add braces and commas to make your copy pasted list look like this: `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`
2. Create an empty 2D line chart (`Excel > Insert > 2D Line Chart`)
3. Right click the empty chart and click `Select Data`
4. In the dialog, click the `Add` button below `Legend Entries (Series)`
5. In the next dialog, select the `Series values` textfield.
6. Enter an equal sign followed by your list, like this: `={1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`
7. Done, click OK in both dialogs to close them

Answer (score 1):

I'm interpreting `without having to add labels etc.` to mean you want something like a sparkline: [image]